# round off milli second to second in spark sql

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

in azure spark sql how to round off millisecond to seconds?

```
Date_format: 2023-06-16T00:00:19.645 
desired_result should be: 2023-06-16T00:00:20
```

I tried using below. but its not giving the right result.

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(timestamp("date_col"))/1000 ,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using these inbuilt functions.

- `unix_timestamp` -> to get epoch timestamp value
- `date_format` -> to get milli seconds
- `concat(".",<int>)` -> to convert milliseconds to decimal
- `round` -> round the milliseconds value

**`Example:`**

```
spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")
spark.sql("""select *,to_timestamp(unix_timestamp(ts) + round(concat(".",date_format(ts, "S")))) round_ts from (
  select timestamp('2023-06-16 00:00:19.645') as ts)a""").\
    show(10,False)

#+-----------------------+-------------------+
#|ts                     |round_ts           |
#+-----------------------+-------------------+
#|2023-06-16 00:00:19.645|2023-06-16 00:00:20|
#+-----------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: I believe the explanation given for "concat" built-in function could be misleading. I would suggest to revisit it and clarify.

Comment: Try running the above code so that you can understand..!

Comment: I understand the code! 
I am just saying the description you have given for "concat" could be misleading. Because it says it "converts ms to dec" (though this is what the overall logic does) this exactly isn't a description for a "inbuilt" (as you have mentioned) func concat.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the timestamp by 1 second and then remove the milliseconds with [`DATE_TRUNC`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#date_trunc)

```
q = """
SELECT
  ts,
  DATE_TRUNC('SECOND', ts + INTERVAL 1 SECOND) AS round_ts
FROM (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2023-06-16 00:00:19.645') AS ts
)
"""
spark.sql(q).show(10, False)

+-----------------------+-------------------+
|ts                     |round_ts           |
+-----------------------+-------------------+
|2023-06-16 00:00:19.645|2023-06-16 00:00:20|
+-----------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: got the answer.  from_unixtime(round(unix_millis(timestamp('2023-06-16T23:59:59.999'))/1000) ,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

Answer (score 0):

Please try this too:

```
from_unixtime(round(unix_millis(timestamp('2023-06-16T23:59:59.999'))/1000) ,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```